# What agency will most economically handle cyber-squatting?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Domain names seem to be controlled by WIPO which has produced UDRP. UDRP rules can be arbitrated by a few different agencies. Is there any way to take ownership of a domain name that is confusingly similar and being squatted?

A client of my owns [`cross-med.com`](http://www.cross-med.com), I'd like to know what it would cost to get the spammer's un-hyphenated version. The best I can see WIPO charges $1,300 for a one-panel judge to decide these matters? Is there no cheaper way to get ownership of a domain from an obvious squatter?

I sent a letter to the registered owner,

> how much are you looking for crossmed.com?

This was his response,

> Hello Evan Carroll You can buy this domain name the original owner
>   asking fixed price at 10000GBP($15200) through the SEDO.COM. May i ask
>   you how much you can offer for this domain? If you  agree $10000 i
>   will contact the original owner to negotiate for you. Thank you.
>   Regards   John Stone Lee

He actually asked for $10,000 for the domain name. I threatened to go to WIPO,

> No, I'll give you $300 or I'll file a UDRP/WIPO. Regards

And, this was his *laughable* response,

> Hi friend Are you menace me now? Sorry but sadly only I hold on this
>   domain Admin contact to charge my credits from the original domain
>   owner. I think you are novice domainer. Please send file to WIPO. Now
>   I can tell you the future result of WIPO, you will lost WIPO fees and
>   it doesn't matter whether you can win the game or not. Maybe I can
>   help you so please let me know when the original domain owner accuse
>   you at the Korea Law Court (if he lose the WIPO game.)  My fee is only
>   $30000 another lawyers asking fee is at least bottom $50000. Thanks
>   you and make an offer $300. Good Luck!   John Stone Lee

How do I get these foreign Capitalist domain-speculating mooches to hand over this domain name?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have a valid trademark in the registrant's country of registration, and is their domain name identical or confusingly similar to your mark?
2. Can you document that the registrant has no rights or legitimate interest in the domain?
3. Can you demonstrate that they registered it in [bad faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy#Process):

   - Whether the registrant registered the domain name primarily for the
     purpose of selling, renting, or otherwise transferring the domain
     name registration to the complainant who is the owner of the
     trademark or service mark;
   - Whether the registrant registered the
     domain name to prevent the owner of the trademark or service mark
     from reflecting the mark in a corresponding domain name, if the
     domain name owner has engaged in a pattern of such conduct; and
   - Whether the registrant registered the domain name primarily for the
     purpose of disrupting the business of a competitor; or
   - Whether by
     using the domain name, the registrant has intentionally attempted to
     attract, for commercial gain, internet users to the registrant's
     website, by creating a likelihood of confusion with the complainant's
     mark.

If the answers to any of the above are "no", then a [UDRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy) complaint, and likely any legal suits, will unfortunately be a waste of time and money.

If the answer to all of them is "yes", then [here](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/udrp/process.html) is a chart of [Fees and Fines](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/udrp/process.html#fees) and a [Timeline](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/udrp/process.html#timeline) for the process, as well as other helpful information. I'd strongly suggest hiring an attorney who specializes in patent & trademark law however, as this can be a complicated matter.

Other than the UDRP process, there is no other way to forcibly get them to hand over the domain, so I'd suggest returning to diplomacy and negotiations with the actual domain owner, instead of their broker if possible.

Or you could focus your efforts on making the site at your domain outperform theirs by adding the best content possible...a hyphen should not prevent you from doing that.